# Performance issue with streaming files from digial ocean storage in laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, filesystems, digital-ocean-spaces

I am using digital ocean space for storing files. I am having performance issue while reading files from there, specially streaming files in a route. Here is my code structure.

Default Driver:

```
FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=digitalocean
```

Disk Config:

```
'digitalocean' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('DIGITALOCEAN_SPACES_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('DIGITALOCEAN_SPACES_SECRET'),
        'endpoint' => env('DIGITALOCEAN_SPACES_ENDPOINT'),
        'region' => env('DIGITALOCEAN_SPACES_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('DIGITALOCEAN_SPACES_BUCKET'),
    ],
```

Controller function:

```
public function view($path)
{
    return Storage::response($filePath);
}
```

This is really slow since it fetches file from the cloud storage and then streams in a url. Is there any way to speedup the process ?

Comment: Did you find a solution to your issue? I am also looking for the same.

Comment: @joeyj, It was really slow on local setup but have good performance with server in same region as of digital ocean.

Comment: thanks for confirming, on my end I found a way to read in chunks which was more relevant for my use case as the files being read needed to be streamed and be flexible for the user to skip/read specific sections.